# Is it possible to bind commits to each other to make them atomic in terms of bisect, cherry-pick, revert, etc?

Tags: git, workflow

Consider the case of a bug fix which causes a small change in the expected output, forcing a minor change in the test suite.  It is extremely convenient to have both changes in the same commit, since it makes it obvious to the reviewer exactly what is changed in the output.  On the other hand,  sometimes you might just want to view the diffs to the source, or the diffs to the expected output and it is much easier to do that if the commits are separate.  Also, the two things are logically distinct so it makes sense to make distinct commits.

I would love to be able to make two distinct commits, but somehow have the two commits linked together in some way (so that I can cherry-pick, revert, etc. both commits as an atomic unit).
Also, if two distinct commits are made, then the test suite will fail on the first commit (unless a third commit is introduced to relax the test suite), making future bisects a pain.   The issue of future bisects failing generally encourages me to make a single commit, but commits should be logically distinct units and a commit to code is logically distinct from a commit to the expected output in the test suite.

Is there a way to make two distinct commits and not have to bend over backwards to prevent bisect from failing on one of them?  (eg, having to explicitly mention commits to skip)

Comment: I think they should be in the same commit exactly because they _are_ logically related.  The src and the unit tests which test it are (by design) coupled.  Also, there's a practical benefit of having every commit be build-able and test-able which I wouldn't abandon without a good reason.

Comment: I agree with Mark.  But I'm hesitant to answer -- what exactly is the question?  The title and the last sentence are two different questions...

Comment: The question is evolving...The motivation is a case in which a two line code change caused several hundred lines of expected output to be slightly altered, and the code change gets buried in the diff because of the amount of changes in the tests.  I want an easy way to view the code diff.  Also, it is often easier if each commit affects only one file, but making groups of commits like that breaks the build and causes bisect to fail.  It feels like the work flow is wrong, and that commits are not granular enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitively keep those changes (code and unit test) as one commit: SCM is also about being able to **reproduce** a given state, and that include both the program and its tests.

If you need to review only code changes, do a git diff on `src` only, not on `tst`.
Since those linked changes remain in one commit, you avoid the bisect issue entirely.

In short, keep it simple ;)

Comment: But git is more than an SCM.  It is a tool for building change sets.  I think the changes are logically distinct (this is proven by the fact that we can talk about "the code changes" and "the test changes" ) so it makes sense to keep them distinct, but best practice (keeping the tree buildable at each commit) conflicts with the logical distinctiveness of the changes.  In this case, it feels like we are twisting our workflow to match the tool, rather than crafting the tool to match the workflow.

Comment: @William: yes, essentially don't try to twist too much the tool ;) One commit for both code change and unit test change is enough.

Comment: "I think the changes are logically distinct (this is proven by the fact that we can talk about "the code changes" and "the test changes" )" -- We can also talk about "the changes in foo.c and the changes in bar.c" as separate changes, even though they are in the same commit. We can even talk about changes in two different *parts* of the same file, even though they're in the same commit. What's important is, in both cases, the two "distinct changes" are part of the single "change" of "fixing bug X" so they belong in the same commit.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: I don't disagree with your analysis, which seems to reinforce my answer. I fail to see why said answer has just been downvoted though.

Comment: Yes, I was agreeing with your answer (and I upvoted it). My comment was more in response to William's comment than to your answer. I should have been more clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can keep them in separate commits in a development branch. After each pair of commits, merge into the feature branch. This should give you the ability to do either way.

Comment: bisect doesn't tread the branch atomically, so doing this will not resolve that issue.

Comment: bisect should skip your intermediate commit of just failing tests. It depends on what the first parent of a merge commit is.